# how to solve text potting with bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, bokeh

Consider the flowing lines of code...

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, save
text = 'I eat rice'
p = figure(title="Bokeh Markers", toolbar_location=None)
p.text(50, 50, text=[text], text_color="firebrick", text_align="center", text_font_size="10pt")
save(p, filename='test.png')
```

Buit it gives lines of warnnings given below

```
C:\Users\~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io.py:430: UserWarning: save() called but no resources were supplied and output_file(...) was never called, defaulting to resources.CDN
warnings.warn("save() called but no resources were supplied and output_file(...) was never called, defaulting to resources.CDN")

C:\Users\~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io.py:440: UserWarning: save() called but no title was supplied and output_file(...) was never called, using default title 'Bokeh Plot'
warnings.warn("save() called but no title was supplied and output_file(...) was never called, using default title 'Bokeh Plot'")
```

Its saving a .png file but which contains nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code.

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file
output_file('test.png')
```

There it the related code in output_file.

```
    self._file = {
        'filename'  : filename,
        'resources' : Resources(mode=mode, root_dir=root_dir),
        'title'     : title
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to save an actual PNG image, then this is not how to do it. The `save` function saves a standard *fully interactive* Bokeh plot, which is actually HTML and JavaScript, and *not* a static PNG image.

If you want a PNG, then you need to *export* the plot, as described in the [Exporting Plots](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html#) section of the User's Guide. Basically you must first install a few optional dependencies (selenium, pillion, and phantomJS) then the necessary code would be more like:

```
export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```